# Get Labels of binary tree

Tags: tree, prolog

I'm struggling with my assignment. 
First we had to define the predicate `tree/1`, where `node(leaf(1), node(leaf(2), leaf(3)))`.  should return true

```
tree(leaf(_)).
tree(node(X,Y)) :- tree(X), tree(Y).
```

Pretty simple.
Now I have to write two predicates, which should essentially work the same. `label/2` and `labels/2`.
`label(B,X)` checks whether `X` is a label in `B` and should print `X=1;X=2;X=3`. for the example given above.(`B` is a binary Tree)
`labels(B,Y)` is the same as `label/2` except that `Y` is a list containing all the labels. `(Y=[1,2,3])`.
What I have right now:

```
label(leaf(Y),X) :-
    %print X? 
label(node(Y,Z),X) :-
    label(Y,X), label(Z,X).
```

and

```
labels(leaf(Y),X) :-
    %append Y to X 
labels(node(Y,Z),X) :-
    labels(Y,X), labels(Z,X).
```

I just can't wrap my head around when prolog prints just true and when it provides a solution for `X`/`Y`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not far.

First: `label/2`.

For the `leaf/1` case, you have simply to unify the second argument with the content of the label; that is

```
label(leaf(X), X).
```

For the `node/2` case, it's wrong (if I understan your requirements)

```
label(Y,X), label(Z,X)
```

because you're asking that `X` is a value present in node `Y` **and** in node `Z`. You should ask that `X` is present in node `Y` **or** in node `Z`. That is (using "or" operator "`;`")

```
label(node(Y,Z),X) :-
    label(Y,X) ; label(Z,X).
```

or better (IMHO) developing two separate clauses

```
label(node(Y, _), X) :-
    label(Y, X).

label(node(_, Y), X) :-
    label(Y, X).
```

Second: `labels/2`

The `leaf/1` case is similar to the `label` with the difference that you have to unify the second argument not with the content of `label/1` (the first argument) but with a **list** contain that content. It's really simple

```
labels(leaf(X), [X]).
```

The `node/2` case is different.

Your solution

```
labels(Y,X), labels(Z,X).
```

is wrong because you're asking that the subnode `Y` and the subnode `Z` are containing the same list of labels.

You have to collect the sublist of `Y`, collect the sublist of `Z` and concatenate they obtaining `X`; that is

```
labels(node(Y, Z), X) :-
    labels(Y, X1),
    labels(Z, X2),
    append(X1, X2, X).
```

Summarizing, I propose the following `label/2` and `labels/2`

```
label(leaf(X), X).

label(node(Y, _), X) :-
    label(Y, X).

label(node(_, Y), X) :-
    label(Y, X).


labels(leaf(X), [X]).

labels(node(Y, Z), X) :-
    labels(Y, X1),
    labels(Z, X2),
    append(X1, X2, X).
```

Comment: Thank you very much. It's amazing how simple a solution in Prolog looks, but getting there as a beginner can get quite complicating. Why would you suggest two separate clauses for label/2, though? Is it to just emphasize the OR?

Comment: @TaikiKurosowa - I'm agree: Prolog is very simple and, more, very elegant but it's a little difficult to adapt at it for a programmer used on other languages. I suggested to use two clauses instead one with an "or" because I find two clauses more human understandable. But can be question of personal taste, I suppose.